# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor X

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Please help me, I can't connect to the database. The error is like the following picture.

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcpgM.png)

[tnsnames.ora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2APF.png)

[listener.ora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD1ss.png)

Where is the problem located? Even though the SID_Name is correct.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Press the radio button Service Name and enter DAML.
The tnsnames.ora file contains the Service Name and not the SID. Service Name and SID may not match.